# Web SQL Web Worker Synchronous

Tags: web-worker, web-sql

First of all, sorry for my English...

Maybe it's a nonsense but i have the following question:

I have a jquery event call...

```
$('#buttonX').click(function(){
    function1();
    alert(function2());
});
```

function1 and function2 have a call to a Web Worker that execute a Web SQL query synchronously:

```
function2()
{
    var dbSync = new Worker('dbSync.js');
    var result;
    dbSync.postMessage();
    dbSync.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
        result = oEvent.data;
        console.log("result: " + result);
        return result;
    };
}
```

CODE dbSync.js:

```
var db = openDatabaseSync('mydb', '1.0', 'my database', 3 * 1024 * 1024);
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    var numRecords;

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        var results = tx.executeSql('SELECT  * FROM foo ', []);
        numRecords = results.rows.length;
        self.postMessage(numRecords);
    });
};
```

But when 'buttonX' is clicked then the first thing that is executed is the alert...even before that function1 and function2 are executed.

I guess it's because Web Workers run always asynchronously but...is there any way for doing all the process synchronous?

...i have tested the process without Web Worker but then, the method OpenDatabaseSync is not supported.

So, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.